# How to change [int] to int in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, integer

Im trying to test if a number can be divided evenly by a group of numbers. This is my code:

```
var arr = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

var text = Int(textField.text!)!

if text % arr === 0 {
}
```

What i'm trying to do is divide variable "text" by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 (if it's divisible by any, perform the action) but i'm unsure how to get the value of the array. And I do not want to have to do:

```
if text % 2 == 0 || text % 3 == 0 || text % 4 == 0
```

etc...

Comment: You can create enum block for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Swifty way to do this would be to use an `if let` to unwrap the optionals and then use the built-in `contains` function to see if the array contains an element that fulfills the predicate.

```
let arr = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
if let text = textField.text, number = Int(text) {    
    if arr.contains({ number % $0 == 0 }) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
for divider in arr {
  if text % divider == 0 {
    // ... 
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: Haha :) at the same time :)

Comment: Looks like same answer like me :), So I'll delete my answer

Comment: There are a few issues with @Mr_Username's code that are not addressed in this answer. Additionally, looping over the array like that and using a break when the element is found is far from an idiomatic way to achieve this behavior in Swift. But it will work.

Comment: I would argue that you replace `break` with `continue`, that way you don't break the loop when fulfilling the condition.

Comment: @Laffen User need to do something if ANY value full fill the logic. Hence if any value go through with if loop you can do something you want and break, because you do not need to find out other values full fill this logic or not.

Comment: Ok, then i don't see the need for a for-loop in the first place. Just use a `.Contains()` instead.. like @overactor suggested in his answer.

Comment: Yeah, That's the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?

```
for value in arr {
     if text % value == 0 {
          // do some action
          break
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in arr {
  if text % i == 0
  {
  }
}
```